# How to cast uint16_t into a float in C++

Tags: c++11, casting, floating-point, c++14, uint16

I am running C++14 on MacOS High Sierra.

I have an `uint16_t` returned from a method and the value can range from 100 to like 8000 odd.

I want to convert it to a `float`. So, if it is 289 then the `float` should be 289.0. I am trying all different ways to cast the `uint16_t` but it my `float` variable always gets zeroes.

```
uint16_t i_value = 289;
```

Tried this:

float f_value = static_cast(i_value);

And tried this:

float f_value = (float)i_value;

But nothing works.

**Question:**
How can I cast `uint16_t` into a `float`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions) (both ways), no cast is required:

```
uint16_t i_value = 289;
float f = i_value;
```

Comment: Gosh. that was silly of me . thanks. will accept you answer in a while